# How to prevent reloading of page using vue, vue recaptcha and axios?

Tags: vue.js, axios, recaptcha

I am really rusty when it comes to vue and coding in general. I have a small project that I am working on that requires a form to talk to a python in backend. I have the backend handled knock on wood, but the front end is becoming a pain. Essentially I want to display a vue-bootstrap modal that notifies the user that they have been sent a verification email (which is now working in backend) everything works in backend. However after the second call back using axios the page re-renders and shows the modal for a few seconds and then the page reloads. I want to avoid the page reload all together.
I have spend about 3 days trying to figure out this out. I have tried countless of configurations to the point where I am losing track of what I've changed. Here is the code I have as of now, any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
// Vue.config.productionTip = false


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  components: {
    'vue-recaptcha': VueRecaptcha
  },
  methods: {
    submit_test: function() {
      //disables submit button so that the user does not hit submit several times
      this.status = "submitting"

      const self = this

      axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/data_privacy_request", json_payload)
        .then((response) => {
          self.sucessfulServerResponse = true

        }).catch((err) => {
          self.serverError = getErrorMessage(err)


          //helper to get a displayable message to the user
          function getErrorMessage(err) {
            let responseBody
            responseBody = err.response
            if (!responseBody) {
              responseBody = err
            } else {
              responseBody = err.response.data || responseBody
            }
            return responseBody.message || JSON.stringify(responseBody)
          }

        }).then(() => {
          self.status = ""
        })

    },
    submit: function() {

      if (this.delete_data || this.access_my_data || this.unsubscribe || this.data_use || this.dont_sell) {
        this.noTypeOfRequest = false
        this.$refs.recaptcha.execute()
      } else {
        this.noTypeOfRequest = true
      }
    },

    onCaptchaVerified: function(recaptchaToken) {

      //disables submit button so that the user does not hit submit several times
      this.status = "submitting"
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset()
      const self = this

      axios.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/recaptcha_verify", {
          'recaptchaToken': recaptchaToken
        })
        .then((response) => {
          self.recaptchaServerResponse = response.data.message
          // Process request
          if (self.recaptchaServerResponse == 'success') {
            self.processRequest()
          }

        }).catch((err) => {
          self.serverError = getErrorMessage(err)
          //helper to get a displayable message to the user
          function getErrorMessage(err) {
            let responseBody;
            responseBody = err.response;
            if (!responseBody) {
              responseBody = err;
            } else {
              responseBody = err.response.data || responseBody;
            }
            return responseBody.message || JSON.stringify(responseBody);
          }

        })



    },
    onCaptchaExpired: function() {
      this.$refs.recaptcha.reset()
    },
    processRequest: function() {
      // Process request
      self = this
      let json_payload = self.build_payload()
      axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/data_privacy_request', json_payload)
        .then((response) => {
          self.$bvModal.show('bv-modal-email-verify')
          self.recaptchaServerResponse = ''
          self.status = ''
        }).catch((err) => {
          self.serverError = getErrorMessage(err)
          //helper to get a displayable message to the user
          function getErrorMessage(err) {
            let responseBody;
            responseBody = err.response;
            if (!responseBody) {
              responseBody = err;
            } else {
              responseBody = err.response.data || responseBody;
            }
            return responseBody.message || JSON.stringify(responseBody);
          }

        })

    },
    build_payload: function() {
      if (this.delete_data) {
        this.subject += 'Delete Data, '
      }
      if (this.access_my_data) {
        this.subject += 'Give Access to my Data, '
      }
      if (this.unsubscribe) {
        this.subject += 'Unsubscribe from Mailing List, '
      }
      if (this.data_use) {
        this.subject += 'Find Out How my Data is Used, '
      }

      if (this.dont_sell) {
        this.subject += 'Stop Data from Being Sold or Used by Third Parties, '
      }
      //remove the last character from string (,)
      this.subject = this.subject.slice(0, -2)
      let user_name = this.first_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.first_name.slice(1) + ' ' + this.last_name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + this.last_name.slice(1)

      this.body = 'Request made by: ' + user_name + '\n' + 'Email: ' + this.email + '\n' + 'Request: ' + this.subject
      this.comment = {
        body: this.body
      }

      //add tag for tier 1
      if (this.unsubscribe) {
        this.tags.push('tier_1')
      }
      //add tag for tier 2
      if (this.delete_data || this.access_my_data || this.data_use || this.dont_sell) {
        this.tags.push('tier_2')
      }

      let payload = {
        ticket_info: {
          subject: this.subject,
          comment: this.comment,
          group_id: this.group_id,
          ticket_form_id: this.ticket_form_id,
          collaborators: this.collaborators,
          tags: this.tags
          //! Assignee id should be Zendesk user
          // assignee_id: this.assignee_id
        },
        user_info: {
          full_name: user_name,
          email: this.email

        }
      }

      return payload
    }
  },


  data() {
    return {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
      email: '',
      delete_data: false,
      access_my_data: false,
      unsubscribe: false,
      data_use: false,
      dont_sell: false,
      request_submitted: false,
      subject: '',
      comment: {},
      body: '',
      ticket_form_id: 360005656567713,
      collaborators: [51024345456598],
      group_id: 360006725656134,
      tags: [],

      //client side validation vars
      status: "",
      recaptchaServerResponse: '',
      serverError: '',
      noTypeOfRequest: false

    }
  }

})
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Data Privacy Request</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.4.3.1.min.css">
  <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
  <!-- Load polyfills to support older browsers -->
  <script src="//polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=es2015%2CIntersectionObserver" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/privacy_request_form.css" />


</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">


    <!-- Form section below-->
    <div class="extra-space-top" v-show="recaptchaServerResponse === '' || recaptchaServerResponse === 'success'">

      <div class="row h-100 justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-10">
          <div class="jumbotron center_div">
            <form @submit.prevent="submit">
              <p class="h4 mb-4 text-center" style="color: #888;">Data Privacy Request</p>

              <div class="form-row mb-4">
                <div class="col">
                  <input v-model="first_name" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="first_name" placeholder="first name" required>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <input v-model="last_name" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="last_name" placeholder="last name" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row mb-4">

                <div class="col">
                  <input v-model="email" class="form-control form-control-lg" type="email" id="email" placeholder="email" required>
                </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-row  mx-auto mt-3">


                <div class="col">

                  <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                    <input v-model="delete_data" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="delete_data">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="delete_data">Delete data</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                    <input v-model="access_my_data" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="access_my_data">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="access_my_data">Access my data</label>
                  </div>

                  <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                    <input v-model="data_use" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="data_use">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="data_use">Find out how my data is being used</label>
                  </div>


                  <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                    <input v-model="dont_sell" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="dont_sell">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="dont_sell">Don't share my data with third parties</label>
                  </div>


                  <div class="custom-control form-control-lg custom-checkbox custom-control-inline">
                    <input v-model="unsubscribe" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="unsubscribe">
                    <label class="custom-control-label" for="unsubscribe">Unsubscribe from mailing list</label>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group">
                <vue-recaptcha ref="recaptcha" @verify="onCaptchaVerified" @expired="onCaptchaExpired" size="invisible" sitekey="6LebOb8UAAAAAKfwWsPsaaasqPq6L0FAatw2owSQdsds3">
                </vue-recaptcha>


                <b-button :disabled="status==='submitting'" type="button" class="my-4" block variant="info" id="show-btn" @click="submit">Submit</b-button>

                <b-modal id="bv-modal-email-verify" hide-footer>
                  <template v-slot:modal-title>
                                                <h1> One more step for extra security! </h1>
                                            </template>
                  <div class="d-block text-center">
                    <h2>You will receive an email shortly at {{email}}. Upon verifying your email your request will be processed.</h3>
                      <p> For additional help you may reach us at privacy@somedomain.com</p>
                  </div>

                  <b-button class="mt-3" block @click="$bvModal.hide('bv-modal-email-verify')">Close Me</b-button>
                </b-modal>

                <!-- <button :disabled="status==='submitting'" onsubmit="return false;" @click="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-lg my-4 btn-block">Submit</button>-->
              </div>
              <div v-cloak class="">
                <div v-show="serverError" class="error">
                  {{serverError}}
                </div>
              </div>
              <p>For more information about our privacy terms <a href="" target="_blank">click here</a> </p>
              <div v-cloak>
                <p v-show="noTypeOfRequest" class="error"> You must select at least one type of request from the checkbox group.</p>
                <p v-show="recaptchaServerResponse !== '' && recaptchaServerResponse !== 'success'" class='error'> Recaptcha Server Error: {{ recaptchaServerResponse}} </p>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>



        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-1"></div>

      </div>

    </div>


    <div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!--<script src="js/vue.2.6.10.min.js" defer></script>-->
  <script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@latest/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=vueRecaptchaApiLoaded&render=explicit" async defer></script>
  <script src="js/vue-recaptcha.1.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/axios.0.18.min.js" defer></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/privacy_request_form.js" defer></script>



</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to use `@click.prevent` to prevent the page from reloading?
Check out the [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)